# How to reset modal contents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

The process is like this.
A user searches any words in a search form. Ajax calls with the word and gets the data, then it will be showed with the modal.

So, I tried to make modal dynamically with ajax.
But the modal contents didn't change once it called.

1) This is the function include a search form and it calls the modal.

```
function answer() {
  //console.log('answer');
  var div = document.createElement('div');

  div.className = 'row';
  div.innerHTML = `<!-- file form start -->
                <!-- file form end -->
                <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label">문의내용</label>
                <!-- text form start -->
                {!! Form::open([ 'route' => ['qnamembercreate', $qnaMemberData->idx], 'method' => 'post', 'files' => true, 'accept-charset' => 'utf-8','class' => 'col-md-10 col-xs-9' ])!!}
                      <div class="col-sm-6 offset-md-6 p-0">
                          <div class="input-group">
                              <input type="text" id="f_search" name="f_search" class="form-control">
                              <span class="input-group-append">
                                  <button type="button" class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn-inverse" onclick="faq_search()">Search</button>
                              </span>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="{{ $qnaMemberData->subject }}">
                      <textarea id="answer_content" class="mb-0" rows="20" style="width:100%;" name="add_answer"></textarea>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input name="fileToUpload" type="file" class="filestyle" data-input="false" id="filestyle-1" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;">
                        <div class="bootstrap-filestyle input-group">
                          <div style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 35.375px; z-index: -1;"></div>
                          <span class="group-span-filestyle " tabindex="0">
                            <label for="filestyle-1" style="margin-bottom: 0;" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm fload-right">
                              <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" class="filestyle-1" data-placeholder="" data-buttontext="첨부파일" data-buttonname="btn-secondary">
                            </label>
                          </span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right ml-1 mt-1" onclick="history.back()">취소</button>
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm float-right mt-1">등록</button>
                  {!! Form::close() !!}
                  <!-- text form end -->`;

  document.getElementById('replyData').appendChild(div);
  document.getElementById('answer').remove();

  $('#answer_content').summernote({
      // placeholder: {!! json_encode($qnaMemberData->content) !!},
      tabsize: 2,
      height: 200,
      lang: 'ko-KR',
      fontNames: ['Gulim',  'Arial', 'Arial Black', 'Comic Sans MS', 'Courier New', ],
      fontNamesIgnoreCheck: ['Gulim'],
  });
}
```

2) This is the 'faq_search' function when the user clicks the 'search' button.

```
function faq_search() {
    var word = $('#f_search')[0].value;
    //console.log(word);

    $.ajax({
        url : '/guidesearch',
        type : 'POST',
        data : {
            keyword: word
        },
        cache : false,
        success : function(data, jqXHR, textStatus) {
            console.log(data);
            faq_popup(data);
        }
    });
}
```

3) This is the 'faq_popup' function which is called after getting the data.

```
function faq_popup(data) {
    var _data = data;
    console.log("here", _data);
    const appendedDiv = $(`
        <div class="modal fade show" tabindex="-1" id="faqModal" role="dialog" style="positon:center;">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
            <!-- Modal content-->
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table mb-0">
                        <tbody></tbody>
                    </table>
                 </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        `);

    const tbody = appendedDiv.find('tbody')[0];
    _data.forEach(({ content, subject }, i) => {
        //console.log(i);
        const tr = tbody.appendChild(document.createElement('tr'));
        tr.innerHTML = `
                      <th scope="row">${i + 1}</th>
                      <td><a style="cursor:pointer">${subject}</a></td>
                     `;
        tr.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', () => getContent(content));
    });

    $('#modal_place').append(appendedDiv);
    $('#faqModal').modal('show');
}
```

I tried to reset the modal with this code below. But the problem is, once the modal content is cleared, the new data is not called at all.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
         console.log("modal closed");
         $(this).find('tbody td').html("");
    });
});
```

I really don't get it. Because I call the 'faq_popup' after the ajax got the data, the new data should be showed. But it doesn't work as I think.
What did I wrong here?

** I also tried to wipe out the whole modal-content. The modal contents doesn't show up at all.

```
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
        console.log("modal closed");
        $(this).find('.modal-content').html("");
 });
```

Comment: When you called faq_popup(data), you obviously found that data contains all the right things to be displayed, yes?

Comment: @KaseyChang yes, I checked the data through ``console.log``, and the data renewed successfully. If you meant that.

Comment: Okay, I don't think you've wiped out the modal in the close code though. You've only wiped out the middle part, the table. I suspect your modal is twice as long when you called faq_popup again, as you only appended. I'd say wipeout everything from #modal_place down, then run faq_popup again and see what happens.

Comment: @KaseyChang Oh, I already did that. I wiped out the modal-contents part, but the result was kind of the same. The modal doesn't show any data at all.

Comment: Well, update the code snippets and show us what you did then.

Comment: @KaseyChang I updated the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Thanks to @KaseyChang, gave me the hint.

The reason was I didn't destroy the modal correctly. The modal was added and added on itself. So I just did this.

```
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
        console.log("modal closed");
        $(this).remove();  <--- here!
});
```

Comment: `$(this).detach()` I think would be a better solution. It does the same thing as `remove()`, but it stores the removed element in memory incase you need to call it again in the future. It makes your app faster as you don't have to regenerate the modal after destroying it.

Answer (score 0):

In the AJAX function you can just `empty()` the modal before the call is made, using `beforeSend`. This way it will happen sequentially:

```js
function faq_search() {
    var word = $('#f_search')[0].value;
    $.ajax({
        url : '/guidesearch',
        type : 'POST',
        data : {
            keyword: word
        },
        cache : false,
        beforeSend : function() {
            $('.modal-content').empty();
        },
        success : function(data, jqXHR, textStatus) {
            console.log(data);
            faq_popup(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: No problem @Jiwon . What about destroying the modal when you close it? Then you can say (if there is a close button): `$('.close').click(function() { $('.modal').remove() })`